# How to delete all rows with a certain value across multiple columns in R without referencing the column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a large data set, so it's not feasible to list out each column name containing a certain value. I want to delete all rows with the value `'BYE'` across 50 columns. I tried this with no luck:

###### Sample data

```
library(dplyr)

(df <- data.frame(
  column1 = c('4', '5', '6', '7', 'BYE'),
  column2 = c('abc', 'def', 'g', 'hi', 'jk'),
  column3 = c('yes', NA, 'BYE', 'no', 'yes'),
  column4 = c('BYE', 'no', 'BYE', NA, 'yes')
))

df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. != 'BYE'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the logic of `any_vars()` into that of `all_vars()`:

```r
df %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(. != 'BYE' | is.na(.)))
```

If you don't want to deal with the missing values, you can replace the operator `==` with `%in%`:

```r
df %>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!. %in% 'BYE'))

#   column1 column2 column3 column4
# 1       5     def    <NA>      no
# 2       7      hi      no    <NA>
```

If you need to select columns flexibly, you can use `filter_at()` instead and pass [tidy-selection helpers](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) into it:

```r
df %>%
  filter_at(vars(___), all_vars(!. %in% 'BYE'))
```

---

Scoped verbs (⁠`_if`⁠, `⁠_at⁠`, ⁠`_all⁠`) have been superseded by the use of `if_all()` or `if_any()` in an existing verb. You can adapt the code as below:

```r
df %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !.x %in% 'BYE'))

df %>%
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ .x %in% 'BYE'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `filter_all()` is superseded; a potential alternative is to use `if_any()`, e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  column1 = c('4', '5', '6', '7', 'BYE'),
  column2 = c('abc', 'def', 'g', 'hi', 'jk'),
  column3 = c('yes', NA, 'BYE', 'no', 'yes'),
  column4 = c('BYE', 'no', 'BYE', NA, 'yes')
)

df %>%
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~grepl('BYE', .x)))
#>   column1 column2 column3 column4
#> 1       5     def    <NA>      no
#> 2       7      hi      no    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

The `if_any()` function allows you to use tidyselect ['selection helpers'](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html) such as `starts_with()` (more details [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)), e.g.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  filter(!if_any(starts_with("column"), ~grepl('BYE', .x)))
#>   column1 column2 column3 column4
#> 1       5     def    <NA>      no
#> 2       7      hi      no    <NA>
```

Or, to filter out rows with "BYE" in column1, column2 or column3:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  filter(!if_any(num_range("column", 1:3), ~grepl('BYE', .x)))
#>   column1 column2 column3 column4
#> 1       4     abc     yes     BYE
#> 2       5     def    <NA>      no
#> 3       7      hi      no    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```r
df[rowSums(df=='BYE', na.rm=TRUE)==0, ]
#   column1 column2 column3 column4
# 2       5     def    <NA>      no
# 4       7      hi      no    <NA>
```